# Default login in multiple login laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have implemented 3 login systems in Laravel. My home page doesn't need a login, and the second page requires authentication of a user login, but it is redirecting to admin login. How can I change this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **3 login system**. Please paste the code of your routes file. And when an unauthenticated user tries to visit a protected page he is redirected to the login route that's how authentication works. Unless you post the routes file code it can't be clear what you are trying to achieve. Also please indicate which route from the route file is the issue for you

Answer (score 0):

There is [RedirectIfAuthenticated.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/1d9e53f90d484e636dfca1812e38953befd97158/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php)  that redirect by default to RouteServiceProvider::HOME which is defined by default as /home. so may it is /admin for you in this file: [RedirectIfAuthenticated.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/1d9e53f90d484e636dfca1812e38953befd97158/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php)